# Date and day of week calculations in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, dayofweek, date-arithmetic

I am trying my best to do this in Actionscript 3 but simply cant get my head around it. I need to calculate how many mondays have passed since a set date up to todays date. Multiply that with 3.5 and deduct it from x. Then calculate how many tuesdays have passed, multiply that by 7 and deduct it from x. Lastly calculate how many wednesdays have passed, multiplied by 7 and deduct it from x.

This will allow me to have an accurate value of x to do other calculations with. IOW a running calendar of remaining hours available based on how many project days have passed.

I then intent to then allow users to book sections of time against the remaining value of x.

So far I can get the day of the week in AS3:

```
    var dayOfWeek_array:Array = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"); 
    var today_date:Date = new Date(); 
    var day_str:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()]; 
    trace("Today is "+day_str);
```

I feel a little out of my depth here. Any advice guidance or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well:

```
public function astest()
{
    var days_count:Object = getDaysCounter(new Date(1984, 6, 6), new Date());

    trace("mondays:", days_count[1]);
    trace("tuesdays:", days_count[2]);
    trace("wednesdays:", days_count[3]);
}

private function getDaysCounter(from:Date, to:Date):Object
{
    //map of the day counter days_count[day] = count;
    var days_count:Object = {};

    //number of millisecons in one 24h day
    var day_ms:int = 24*60*60*1000;

    //the number of 24h day passed since "from" date
    var days_passed:int = (to.time - from.time)/day_ms;

    var iter_date:Date = from;
    //number of full weeks since "from" date
    var full_weeks:int = days_passed/7;

    for(var d:int = 0; d < 7; d++)
        days_count[d] = full_weeks;

    var last_day:int = from.day;
    var extra_days:int = days_passed%7 + last_day;
    for(var i:int=last_day; i < extra_days; i++)
    {
        //add 1 day to the current time
        iter_date.time += day_ms;
        days_count[iter_date.day]++;
    }

    return days_count;
}
```

this code doesn't count the current day, that is if today is tuesdays it will not count in the result until tomorrow, counts only full 24h day passed.

Comment: Hi @fsbmain Thank you for the very quick response.

This looks like the right thing. I will give it a go and see how I get on. Thanks in advance